# onChange for picker not working after closing app and opening again

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm building a app and I have a `Picker` wheel and I figured out you can use `.onChange` to detect a change in the picker.

So I ended up with this code:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    let languages = ["English", "Chineese", "French", "Spanish"]
    @State private var language = "English"
    var body: some View {
        Picker("Language", selection: $language) {
            ForEach(languages, id: \.self) {
                Text($0)
            }
        }
        .pickerStyle(.wheel)
        .onChange(of: language) { newValue in
            print("Worked!")
        }
    }
}
```

It works as expected the when first building and launching the app and prints out "Worked!" properly. But closing the app and reopening it, I can still use the picker, but when I move the picker it does not print "Worked!". I couldn't find out why or find anything online about it, so I'm really confused.

Here's a GIF showing what's happening:

[image: GIF showing problem]

Comment: looks like you are totally closing the App, then re-starting it from the `device`.
 For the `print` to display in the Xcode console, you need to start (or re-start) the app from `Xcode`.

Comment: Really? I did not know that. Let me test that out

Comment: You'll also notice that the "Stop button" at the top of Xcode disappears when you terminate the app in the simulator.
This means that Xcode's debugging mode has been turned off, which means that you will no longer be able to see logs in Xcode's console.